# How to retrieve total amount of one column that is dependent by another column from mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to retrieve the day(dateAndTime),SUM(amount) group by day(dateAndTime) but when the type is "withdraw",The amount will be subtracted instead of adding. How do I achieve that?

My Query for now:

```
  select day(dayAndTime),SUM(amount) from table group by day(dayAndTime)
```

TABLE

```
id  |   username    |    type       |    amount     |   dateAndTime
    |               |               |               |
 1  |    user1      |    withdraw   |       10      | 2016-01-27 03:35:07 
 2  |    user2      |    deposit    |       20      | 2016-01-27 03:35:07 
 3  |    user1      |    deposit    |       40      | 2016-01-27 03:35:07 
 4  |    user2      |    withdraw   |       20      | 2016-01-27 03:35:07
```

Comment: `..SUM(CASE WHEN type='deposit' THEN amount ELSE -amount END)..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with a case statement like this:

```
select day(dateAndTime),SUM(CASE WHEN type='deposit' THEN amount ELSE -amount END) 
from table1 group by day(dateAndTime)
```

you can test it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24474/3/0)

---

don't forget you made an typo in your query

```
dayAndTime
```

should be

```
dateAndTime
```

Answer (score 0):

check out [case](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjRro6YrcrKAhXEyT4KHXQ_CQ8QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.7%2Fen%2Fcase.html&usg=AFQjCNF6YPO3h6jq0kBzdYFVY5oFhUTbEA&sig2=32DF3axrrO_1KZdW4dvCaQ&bvm=bv.112766941,d.dmo)

```
SELECT dateAndTime, SUM(amount) 
FROM (
  SELECT dateAndTime, 
    CASE type
      WHEN 'withdraw' THEN amount * -1
      WHEN 'deposit' THEN amount
    END as amount
  FROM table
)
GROUP BY DAY(dateAndTime)
```